# Failure in installing packages

Tags: r, package, rstudio

I have written my code a-2 months ago and i try to reuse it, but the installation of packages fails and i become this warning:

```
install.packages("devtools")
library("devtools")

> library("devtools")
Loading required package: usethis
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘usethis’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘cli’ 3.3.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.4.0 is required
Error: package ‘usethis’ could not be loaded
```

Although i reinstalled RStudio and R, tried to upadte all packages and install all their dependencies etc, it fails to install the updates/packages. Do you have any idea? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Restart R so no packages are loaded. Then run `install.packages("cli")` first. That will hopefully update the dependency. Make sure you aren't automatically loading any packages are start up. After you restart, run `sessionInfo()` to make sure the `cli` package has not been loaded somehow. You cannot update packages after they have been loaded into the current session.

Comment: Thank u very much, i needed to delete all packages and all hidden files from pc so that i reinstall them and then it worked.

Answer (score -1):

first you need to check from bottom right (Packages) and search for `devtools` if you found check if installed or not, also you can write `?devtools` to see if help page show up for **Package development tools for R**, if you want to use the package you can write `devtools::` and follow it with the name of function.